# How to resolve redis connect runtime error?

Tags: nginx, lua, redis, openresty

I am trying to access redis from a lua script in my nginx.conf file on my openresty nginx server. The following is the lua script, I am using the content_by_lua_file directive to refer to it.

```
local redis = require "resty.redis"
local red = redis:new()
local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
if not ok then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Redis connection failure: " .. err)
    return
end
```

I get runtime error ... attempt to call method 'connect' (a nil value)

What's going on here?
Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet works fine on my OpenResty. I use openresty/openresty:xenial Docker image.

Comment: Well I had to add this directive lua_package_path "/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/?.lua;;"; in the http context then it worked

Comment: IMO if it will package.path issue you should get an error on require (first line)

Comment: but that wasn't the case unfortunately

Comment: Did you saved the issue?

Comment: wow so much has happened since this question was posted. Unfortunately I cannot remember what the solution was but the comment I added above indicates that I found the answer :)